# Battery consumption

Tags: battery, task-management

My stats are the follwing:
`Android system 37%`,
`Stand by 36%`,
`Inactivity 14%`,
`Voice call 3%`.

I touch in android and appears a lot of programs like
`alertrecipients,
google backup transport,
error,
?Perso?,
Tasks,
bluetooth test,
popupuiReceiver,
wssyncmlnps,
mobile tracker,
DRM,
definitions,
wlan test,
self test mode,
wipeoutreceiver,
VPN services,
android sistem,
facory test,
preconfig and
service mode`.

Can I turn off some of those tasks in managment, or better asked, is there any of those I cannot stop, that is essential to the phone?
Mostly I just need phone, some ocasional pictures and sms, maybe 2/3 times a week use an app!

Comment: What? I'm sorry, but your post is completely incomprehensible. (I understand that English may not be your first language.) Fixing the formatting would go a long way, but I really think you need to clarify what it is you're after.

Comment: markissimo, helped a lot, thanks and yes its not my native language, sorry for the incovinience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in settings, running applications and close the ones that you don't need. The application that the system needs you won't be able to close. 
Or you can just uninstall the undesired ones as well.

And reformat your question so it makes more sense and it's understandable.

Comment: i´ve done that and for now is working just fine with Android system just 4%. At the end of the day ill post here if this have reduced the battery consumption.

Comment: After 1 day and 3 hours and follwing your advice i have full battery and android consumption is only 7%, thank you all who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This was my first cell phone with android sistem (Samsung Galaxy Ace android 2.3), i just have for 4 days, so some questions arose, like this one but is pretty simple to solve, and i hope that can help another people. To solve the problem is going to settings, turn off some applications that i/you dont need, if you like me dont need 3G always working as the GPS or WiFi, just turn them off, but pay attention if you run out of battery the app's will turn on when you turn on your cell phone.